# Is there some built-in which marks the last of a sequence?

Tags: python, generator

I need something like this:

```
>>> for i in mark_last([1, 2, 3]):
...  print(i)
... 
(1, False)
(2, False)
(3, True)
```

I implemented it this way, but...

```
def mark_last(li):
    items = iter(items)
    try:
        prev = next(items)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    for item in items:
        yield prev, False
        prev = item
    yield prev, True
```

Is there a built-in for this? Or a shorter way to do it? Maybe something combined with `itertools.groupby()`? – Tricks with `len()` are not accepted, because they don’t work with generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some built-in which marks the last of a sequence?

No, there isn't.

Your function is fine except for two points:

1. How does it handle an empty sequence?
2. Instead of `raise StopIteration` you should just `break`; eventually a `raise StopIteration` will result in a `RunTimeError` ([PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)).

Comment: Your no. 2 is a good point. Regarding no. 1: empty sequence → no elements → no last element → nothing to mark. – So, by design, the print loop is not entered at all.

Comment: @RobertSiemer: If you look at line 2 of `mark_last`: `last = next(li)` -- this is the same issue as 2: it works now, but won't in a post-PEP479 world.

Answer (score 2):

You could define `mark_last` in terms of `iwindow`, which returns a sliding
window over an iterable.

```
import itertools as IT

def iwindow(iterable, n=2):
    """
    Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the sequence.
    s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...
    """
    iterables = IT.tee(iterable, n)
    iterables = (IT.islice(it, pos, None) for pos, it in enumerate(iterables))
    for result in IT.izip(*iterables):
        yield result

def mark_last(iterable):
    for i, j in iwindow(iterable):
        yield i, False
    yield j, True

for i in mark_last([1, 2, 3]):
    print(i)
```

yields

```
(1, False)
(2, False)
(3, True)
```

Note that you might be able to solve your problem with `iwindow` directly, by-passing the need for `mark_last`.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't make the code shorter, but perhaps that shouldn't be the
goal. `iwindow` is a more commonly needed design pattern. If you keep `iwindow`
in your toolbox (as, say, in a `util.py` module), you'll be able to solve many
sliding-window problems in terms of it. `mark_last` is just one example.

Answer (score 2):

A neater version of what you gave would be

```
def mark_last(items):
    items = iter(items)

    prev = next(items)
    for item in items:
        yield prev, False
        prev = item

    yield item, True
```

Note that using a bare `next` to raise `StopIteration` is deprecated, though, so you might want to use an explicit `try...except`.

Comment: Yeah, `for...in` is way better. I’ll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3+

This might be a little hard on performance for large lists...

```
>>> def mark_last(iterable):
...     *others, last = iterable
...     for element in others:
...             yield (element, False)
...     yield (last, True)
...
>>> for i in mark_last([1, 2, 3]):
...     print(i)
...
(1, False)
(2, False)
(3, True)
```

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> If the target list contains one target prefixed with an asterisk,
>   called a “starred” target: The object must be a sequence with at least
>   as many items as there are targets in the target list, minus one. **The
>   first items of the sequence are assigned, from left to right, to the
>   targets before the starred target. The final items of the sequence are
>   assigned to the targets after the starred target. A list of the
>   remaining items in the sequence is then assigned to the starred target**
>   (the list can be empty).

This is what's being done on the `*others, last = iterable` line, but in reverse.

Comment: Is there a last element of an infinite iterator?

Comment: If you know that there's the possibility of this function being called on an infinite iterator, you should use Veedrac's solution.